# VBA Excel macro run-time error 1004 and hidden object

Tags: excel, vba

Long-time macro has stopped functioning. Error received: "Run-time Error '1004': Sorry, we couldn't find Registration-CM-Before.xls. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"

Macro takes raw data from Registration-CM-Before spreadsheet and moves it into CM Master. Both spreadsheets are open and active. Last used this macro in May 2023 and zero function issues.

The Reg CM Before sheet was created with an older version of Excel and runs in compatibility mode - not sure if this is contributing to issue or not.

Used VBA debug. This line of code is highlighted:

[image: Debug screen]

Not sure how to correct the issue.

Comment: Pass the full filepath?

Comment: Do you want all 3 module codes or just Module 3 where the highlighted code appears?

Comment: Are `Registration-CM-Before.xls` and `CM-Master.xlsm` in the same folder?

Comment: Yes, in the same folder and when I run the macro, both are open, CM Master is the active on-top sheet and cell B2 is highlighted.

Comment: When you try to open a file using only the file name, you're relying on a specific "current directory".  This will not be a robust way to open the file.   Situation may also be further complicated if your files are stored on (eg) SharePoint.

Comment: The files are emailed to me and I download them to my hard drive and run them from there. When the process is complete, ie all data moved, I will either email them back to the person using the data or put them on Dropbox for easy retrieval.

Comment: `Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Registration-CM-Before.xls"` if both workbooks are saved in the same location.

Comment: Thanks, Tim Williams, for the info. I updated the code and verified that the path to the files is correct yet I still get the same yellow break/error that I had before. I cannot execute it from Excel using the macro BUT I was able to run it from Visual Basic and it worked? I don't understand.

Comment: Thanks, Everyone, especially Tim Williams. I updated the code as you suggested and still had issues but once I told VBA to run the code, it seemed to rewrite things because now the macro performs properly. I appreciate the assistance.